# converting hard text cross-references to real cross-references and looping through paragraphs does not find all instance

Tags: vba, loops, ms-word, cross-reference

I have a large Word doc with many figure references that are hard text. I'd like to update them to real cross-references. My code only replaces two instances midway through the document, and I can't figure out how to improve it.

```
Dim myFigs As Variant
myFigs = ActiveDocument.GetCrossReferenceItems(ReferenceType:="Figure")

' Loop through all paragraphs in the document to update cross-references
For Each para In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
    If para.Style = "Body Text" Then
        ' Search for plain text cross-references to figures
        Set crossRefRange = para.Range
        Do While crossRefRange.Find.Execute(FindText:="Figure [0-9]{1,}\.[0-9]{1,}", MatchWildcards:=True)
            ' Store the found range
            Set crossRefRange = crossRefRange.Duplicate
            ' Extract the figure number
            figureNumber = Split(crossRefRange.Text, " ")(1)
            ' Check if the figure number exists in the dictionary
            If figureCaptionDict.Exists(figureNumber) Then
                Dim searchString As String
                searchString = figureNumber
                
                For i = LBound(myFigs) To UBound(myFigs)
                    If InStr(myFigs(i), searchString) > 0 Then
                        fig = myFigs(i)
                        Debug.Print figureNumber & " " & fig
                        crossRefRange.Select
                        Selection.Delete
                        Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart
                        Selection.InsertCrossReference ReferenceType:="Figure", ReferenceKind:=wdOnlyLabelAndNumber, _
                                                        ReferenceItem:=i, InsertAsHyperlink:=True
                        Exit For ' Exit the loop after inserting cross-reference
                    End If
                Next i
            End If
        Loop
    End If
Next para
```

Comment: I recall `Find` has many "sticky" options, so maybe make sure the ones you're not explicitly setting are doing what you expect?  https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/MacrosVBA/ClearFind.htm

Comment: I don't think this is the source of the problem, but AFAICS at the moment, your code will just process every match after the first one, regardless of paragraph style. To avoid that you add an If block starting (say) If crossRefRange.InRange(para.Range), after the "Set crossRefRange = crossRefRange.Duplicate" line (which I am not sure you need anyway!). Otherwise, IMO it's really a question of whether the numbers in your existing captions actually match the ones in the text when you do "If InStr(myFigs(i), searchString) > 0 Then" (That works OK in my tests but worth checking IMO).